# Spying on service that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a service that retrieves data with a cache and a fallback to $http, and I'm trying to mock out calls to the service in a controller spec using jasmine spies. However, when I call `scope.$digest`, the actual service is being called and HTTP call is being made.

I have tried using all combinations of `[$rootScope|scope].[$apply|$digest]()` and my HTTP calls are still being made. However if I return something other than a promise from my spy, such as a string, I will get an error that `then` is undefined as a function, so it appears the spy is stubbing the function successfully?

### Jasmine Test

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();

  // Should be called by each test after mocks and spies have been setup
  startContoller = function() {
    $controller('SearchCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      $stateParams: { q: 'test' }
    });
  };
}));

it('sets error message when no results', inject(function(QuestionService, $q) {
  var deferred;
  spyOn(QuestionService, 'search').and.callFake(function() {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.reject();
    return deferred.promise;
  });

  startContoller();
  scope.$digest();

  expect(scope.error).toBe(true);
}));
```

### Controller

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'QuestionService',
  function($scope, $stateParams, QuestionService) {
    var query = $stateParams.q;

    $scope.page = 1;
    QuestionService.search(query, $scope.page).then(function(questions) {
      if (questions.length === 0) {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = 'No Results';
      } else {
        $scope.questions = questions;
      }
    }, function() {
      $scope.error = true;
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: Have you also tried with injecting the mocked service to controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dmahapatro's comment is the way to go.

As you are retreiving the controller using $controller('SearchCtrl'...), your service is already instanciated by the time your "it" block is executed, so spying on it has no effect.

You should be injecting the mocked service in your $controller call.
Also, no need for your startController() function, as invoking $controller will execute the controller's logic.

```
var QuestionServiceMock, deferred;
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();

  QuestionServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('QuestionService', ['search']);
  QuestionServiceMock.search.andCallFake(function () {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.reject();
    return deferred.promise;
  });
  $controller('SearchCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    $stateParams: { q: 'test' },
    QuestionService: QuestionServiceMock
  });
}));

it('sets error message when no results', inject(function(QuestionService, $q) {
  scope.$apply();

  expect(scope.error).toBe(true);
}));
```